# Newly added SecurityFilterChain not included in filter chain

Tags: spring, spring-security

- Spring Security: 5.6.2
- Wildfly 24 Application Server with container managed authentication setup

So far we were using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for security configuration to apply our own set of rule for authorization with Spring Security, but now `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is going to be deprecated from 5.7 ([this](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) blog post) we are moving to `SecurityFilterChain` mechanism.

This is the code snippet for SecurityFilterChain setup.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    String role = "ADMINUSER";
    
    http.jee().mappableAuthorities(role);
    http.csrf().disable()
    
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/j_security_check").permitAll()

    // OWASP Pen Test: X-Frame-Options header
    http.headers().frameOptions().deny();
    
    // Remainder of app must have ADMINUSER role
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole(role)

    return http.build();
}
```

On enabling TRACE log level for Spring security, found that this filter is recognized and printed permission rules on log, see below:

```
o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:72] Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/assets/**']
o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:72] Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/login/**']
o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:72] Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/j_security_check']
o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource [ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:72] Adding web access control expression [hasRole('ROLE_ADMINUSER')] for Ant [pattern='/**']
```

But eventually it has put these request patterns to secured resources list, from the log:

```
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:208] Securing GET /assets/login/Prod-Logo-55b1334f6df931972f65a053d027da82.png
o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:208] Securing GET /assets/login/login-4af79e08f88a8922f7b81b96f782eb39.css
```

It does not include these unsecured resources to login page and so the login page looks unpleasant because static resources are not available. And moreover, on providing correct user credentials, it redirects to Spring's default login page, instead of welcome page specified in web.xml.

Two questions:

1. Why does it redirect to Spring Security's default login page on providing correct user credentials
2. As the permissions for static resources are confirmed and verified in the log, then why do they put in secured resources list?

Please help by pointing out where I am missing on setup.

Comment: Did anything else change in your application or is the only change moving from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to a `SecurityFilterChain`?

Comment: We moved from grails 4.0.3 to 5.1. So earlier it was Spring Security 5.1.8 and now it is at 5.6.2. But so far everything is version change, no code change at all. This is the first thing which broke. And as `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is going to deprecated in Spring security 5.7, we are moving to Filter Chain.

Comment: To clarify, if you use the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and Spring Security 5.6.2 and Grails 5.1, is the configuration broken?

Comment: Yes, it throws runtime exception `IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.`

Comment: Do you have multiple `SecurityFilterChain` or multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? I'm not familiar with Wildfly, it's possible that is also bringing in some kind of configuration.

Comment: Before upgrade there were two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. But right now after upgrade we are trying with single `SecurityFilterChain` bean. It was working fine with same version Wildfly before upgrade. So I think this is after upgrade only, mostly because of Spring Security?

Comment: And what's happened with another WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? Did you just remove it?

Comment: Currently there is no `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is configured. The try is to make it run with `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: My suggestion is to first get this working with the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and the dependency upgrades. Once that is working you can update to a `SecurityFilterChain`. The error message `Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain.` means that there is a `SecurityFilterChain` coming from somewhere other than your application (since you're only using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`). Try to figure out where that  `SecurityFilterChain` is coming from. It's likely one of your dependencies.

Comment: Setup a new grails project and tried to reproduce it. the error `Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one` was also there. To fix, gradually removed dependencies and found that if we comment `org.grails:grails-web-boot`, then there is no error. But it will make it non-web deployment. And then finally found that on `Application.groovy` if we have `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ SecurityAutoConfiguration.class ])` then it works fine. So basically Spring Boot configures SpringSecurity as part of autoconfiguration step. So its Spring's fault?